# Why does Gradle setCharAt fail?

Tags: groovy

I'm new to Groovy / Gradle but it really seems to me like this should work:

```
 def test  = new StringBuilder("This file: ${fileName}")
 char testDot = '.'
 int testlngth = test.length() - 5

 println test.setCharAt(testlngth,testDot).toString()
```

...but it results in:

```
 No signature of method: java.lang.StringBuilder.setCharAt() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Character, java.lang.Integer) values: [12, .]
  Possible solutions: setCharAt(int, char), getChars(), charAt(int), deleteCharAt(int), deleteCharAt(int)
```

Any body know why?  Something having to do with typeing between the languages perhaps? I've noticed that the primitives have been boxed but I don't know a way around that in Groovy / Gradle.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Groovy/Gradle, but you in Java you can unbox manually with: `Integer.valueOf( ImAnInteger )` and so on, if that turns out to be needed.

Comment: [`StringBuilder.setCharAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt%28int,%20char%29) is a void method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the `index` then the replacement `char`:

```
setCharAt(myIndex, myChar);
```

Comment: Whoops, bad example. The real code has it right. Will fix.

Comment: Wait, I found something else. Fixing also.

Comment: OK, that's everything I can think of to fix. Still fails.

Comment: Should you run across a similar problem in the future, note that the error message actually tells you the problem is your args are `(java.lang.Character, java.lang.Integer)` and it suggests `setCharAt(int, char)` as a possible solution.

Comment: @JohnHascall ...which didn't work. I figured it out. It's because setCharAt was never meant to be chained. If you chain it, you wind up with a null in their. Naturally what you do without thinking is returning setCharAt(...).toString()  Same sort of 11th hour mistake I make when it's the end of the day and I'm brain tired.

Comment: Yup, setCharAt() returns null rather than something which would be useful to chain with (jQuery et al have spoiled us all :)  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt%28int,%20char%29

Comment: @JohnHascall, `setCharAt` doesn't return null. It's a `void` method.